# Comparing two files with respective fields and output required in a specific format

Tags: bash, shell, awk, compare

I am comparing two files

food1.txt file  and compares food2.txt file, like this

```
# cat food1.txt 
pizza=1ea
chicken=5ea
tooboo=4ea
orange=2ea
```

```
# cat food2.txt 
pizza=2ea
chicken=5ea
grape=3ea
tooboo=4ea
melon=1ea
```

- my work...

```
FOOD1=`cat ./food1.txt`
FOOD2=`cat ./food2.txt`

echo "$FOOD1" | while read ACCOUNT
do
grep -w $ACCOUNT ./food2.txt  >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
echo "-----[  OK  ] : $ACCOUNT"
else
echo "-----[ WARN ] : $ACCOUNT"
fi
done
```

- output.. but i don't like it

```
-----[ WARN ] : pizza=1ea
-----[  OK  ] : chicken=5ea
-----[  OK  ] : tooboo=4ea
-----[ WARN ] : orange=2ea
```

I want to print the comparison target together

- I want output, like this

```
food2.txt                   food1.txt
pizza=2ea   : [ NotMatch ] : pizza=1ea
            : [    OK    ] : chicken=5ea
            : [    OK    ] : tooboo=4ea
            : [ NotExist ] : orange=2ea
grape=3ea   : [ NotExist ] :
melon=1ea   : [ NotExist ] :
```

Is it possible? please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your efforts. For line `pizza=2ea   : [ NotMatch ] : pizza=1ea` shouldn't this also come as `non-exits` etc? Since both lines are not matching in both the files. Please clarify on same once.

Comment: Because this item (pizza) is exist but doesn't match , it write Not-match.    

 each files  Orange and grape melon items do not exist, so it write "NotExist".....        

in food1. txt file does not exist grape and melon and food2.txt does not exist orange item

Comment: Are `pizza=2ea` and `pizza=1ea` aligned on one row because left of the `=` sign they match (both `pizza`), or because they are both on the same line in the input files (both line 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="="
  print ARGV[1]"                   "ARGV[2]
}
FNR==NR{
  arr1[$1]=$2
  next
}
($1 in arr1){
  if($2==arr1[$1]){
     print  "           :[    OK     ] : " $0
  }
  else if($2!=arr1[$1]){
     print $1 FS arr1[$1]"  :[ NotMatch  ] : "$0
  }
  arr2[$1]
  next
}
{
  print $0"  :[ NotExist  ] : "
}
END{
  for(i in arr1){
     if(!(i in arr2)){
        print "           :[ NotExist  ] : "i FS arr1[i]
     }
  }
}
' food1.txt food2.txt
```

With your shown samples, following will be ***output***:

```
food1.txt                   food2.txt
pizza=1ea  :[ NotMatch  ] : pizza=2ea
           :[    OK     ] : chicken=5ea
grape=3ea  :[ NotExist  ] :
           :[    OK     ] : tooboo=4ea
melon=1ea  :[ NotExist  ] :
           :[ NotExist  ] : orange=2ea
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                                       ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS="="                                                     ##Setting field separator as = here.
  print ARGV[1]"                   "ARGV[2]                  ##Printing passed Input_file names here.
}
FNR==NR{                                                     ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when food1.txt is being read.
  arr1[$1]=$2                                                ##Creating array named arr1 with index of 1st field and value is $2.
  next                                                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in arr1){                                                ##Checking condition if $1 is present in arr1 then do following.
  if($2==arr1[$1]){                                          ##Checking condition if 2nd field is equal to arr1 value.
     print  "           :[    OK     ] : " $0                ##Printing ok message with current line of food2.txt here.
  }
  else if($2!=arr1[$1]){                                     ##Else(in case 2nd field is NOT equal to arr1 value) then do following.
     print $1 FS arr1[$1]"  :[ NotMatch  ] : "$0             ##Printing first field FS value of arr1 followed by NotMatch followed by current line from food2.txt.
  }
  arr2[$1]                                                   ##Making an entry of current $1 for arr2 array here.
  next                                                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print $0"  :[ NotExist  ] : "                              ##printing current line followed by NotExist statement.
}
END{                                                         ##Starting END block for this program from here.
  for(i in arr1){                                            ##Traversing through arr1 elements here.
     if(!(i in arr2)){                                       ##Checking condition if key i is NOT present in arr2 then do following.
        print "           :[ NotExist  ] : "i FS arr1[i]     ##printing NOtExist statements followed by i FS and arr1 value.
     }
  }
}
' food1.txt food2.txt                                        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply & explanation ... 

one more question  

You used '=' as the field delimiter, is it also possible to compare with regular strings? 

For example, a slightly complex string  

`/    80G    xfs  /rootvg-lv_root  :[ NotMatch  ] :  /    85G    xfs  /rootvg-lv_root`
...Is it possible?

Comment: @hyun.ji, yes we can do it. In my humble opinion open a new question with your efforts(like you added here) and samples of input and expected output and let me know we can discuss it there

Comment: of course.  I will resume my question as you said.

Comment: `stackoverflow.com/questions/71083171`    I opened a new question as you suggested. Please look at my question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As `bash` is tagged, here's a solution using associative arrays. The first `while` loop populates the array reading the first file. The second `while` loop iterates over the second file, checks whether keys and/or values match with entries in the array, and deletes them. Finally the `for` loop iterates over the remaining "unchecked" items in the array.

```sh
out() {
  if   [[      -z "$3" ]]; then l="$1"    m="                " r="$2"
  elif [[      -z "$2" ]]; then l="$3=$1" m=": [ NotExist ] :" r=""
  elif [[      -z "$1" ]]; then l=""      m=": [ NotExist ] :" r="$3=$2"
  elif [[ "$2" == "$1" ]]; then l=""      m=": [    OK    ] :" r="$3=$2"
  else                          l="$3=$1" m=": [ NotMatch ] :" r="$3=$2"; fi
  printf '%-10s %s %-10s\n' "$l" "$m" "$r"
}

f1=food1.txt
f2=food2.txt

out "$f2" "$f1"

declare -A f
while IFS== read -r k v; do f[$k]=$v; done < "$f2"

while IFS== read -r k v; do out "${f[$k]}" "$v" "$k"; unset f[$k]; done < "$f1"

for k in "${!f[@]}"; do out "${f[$k]}" "" "$k"; done
```

```
food2.txt                   food1.txt 
pizza=2ea  : [ NotMatch ] : pizza=1ea 
           : [    OK    ] : chicken=5ea
           : [    OK    ] : tooboo=4ea
           : [ NotExist ] : orange=2ea
grape=3ea  : [ NotExist ] :           
melon=1ea  : [ NotExist ] :
```