# Compare two files with string and output required for specific format

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, compare

Thank you for your answer at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080087`
@RavinderSingh13

In questions/71080087, I compared two files by the field delimiter.

one more question...
I want to ask a more detailed question

This is a list of file systems provided by each of the two servers.

```
cat volume1.txt (by server1)
/         80G    xfs  /dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root 
/boot     1014M  xfs  /dev/sda2 
/boot/efi 500M   vfat /dev/sda1
/swlogs   10G    xfs  /dev/mapper/datavg-lv_swlogs
```

```
# cat volume2.txt (by server2)
/         33G    xfs  /dev/mapper/rhel-root 
/boot/efi 599M   vfat /dev/sda1 
/boot     1014M  xfs  /dev/sda2
```

Is it possible to output as below? (order of the lines doesn't matter)

```
volume1.txt                                                        volume2.txt
/       80G    xfs  /dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root     : [ NotMatch ] : /       33G    xfs  /dev/mapper/rhel-root 
/boot     1014M  xfs  /dev/sda2                    : [    OK    ] : 
/boot/efi 500M   vfat /dev/sda1                    : [ NotMatch ] : /boot/efi 599M   vfat /dev/sda1
/swlogs   10G    xfs  /dev/mapper/datavg-lv_swlogs : [ NotExist ] :
```

my work...

```
FOOD1=`cat ./food1.txt`
FOOD2=`cat ./food2.txt`

echo "$FOOD1" | while read ACCOUNT
do
grep -w $ACCOUNT ./food2.txt  >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
echo "-----[  OK  ] : $ACCOUNT"
else
echo "-----[ WARN ] : $ACCOUNT"
fi
done
```

If you don't understand my question please tell me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, please do mention on what basis you want to compare the lines? Do you want to compare complete line values with each other? OR some specific fields? Please clarify the same once.

Comment: Thanks for reading.  I want to compare the line values ​​of each other in one complete line. 
  For example, 'NotMatch' is output if some one character is wrong in that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  print ARGV[1]"                   "ARGV[2]
}
FNR==NR{
  arr1[$1]=$0
  next
}
($1 in arr1){
  if($0==arr1[$1]){
     print  $0 "           :[    OK     ] : "
  }
  else if($0!=arr1[$1]){
     print arr1[$1]"  :[ NotMatch  ] : "$0
  }
  arr2[$1]
  next
}
{
  print $0"  :[ NotExist  ] : "
}
END{
  for(i in arr1){
     if(!(i in arr2)){
        print arr1[i]"           :[ NotExist  ] : "
     }
  }
}
' volume1.txt  volume2.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                                       ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  print ARGV[1]"                   "ARGV[2]                  ##Printing passed Input_file names here.
}
FNR==NR{                                                     ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when food1.txt is being read.
  arr1[$1]=$0                                                ##Creating array named arr1 with index of 1st field and value is $0.
  next                                                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in arr1){                                                ##Checking condition if $1 is present in arr1 then do following.
  if($0==arr1[$1]){                                          ##Checking condition if whole line is equal to arr1 value.
     print  "           :[    OK     ] : " $0                ##Printing ok message with current line of food2.txt here.
  }
  else if($0!=arr1[$1]){                                     ##Else(in case whole line is NOT equal to arr1 value) then do following.
     print arr1[$1]"  :[ NotMatch  ] : "$0             ##Printing first field FS value of arr1 followed by NotMatch followed by current line from food2.txt.
  }
  arr2[$1]                                                   ##Making an entry of current $1 for arr2 array here.
  next                                                       ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print $0"  :[ NotExist  ] : "                              ##printing current line followed by NotExist statement.
}
END{                                                         ##Starting END block for this program from here.
  for(i in arr1){                                            ##Traversing through arr1 elements here.
     if(!(i in arr2)){                                       ##Checking condition if key i is NOT present in arr2 then do following.
        print "           :[ NotExist  ] : "i FS arr1[i]     ##printing NOtExist statements followed by i FS and arr1 value.
     }
  }
}
' volume1.txt  volume2.txt                                   ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: your teaching has been a great help to me, thanks again...     

in your code line number 14  
`print $1 FS arr1[$1]" :[ NotMatch ] : "$0`   is output like this
`/ /         80G    xfs  /dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root   :[ NotMatch  ] : /         33G    xfs  /dev/mapper/rhel-root`  
  It looks like two / (root). 
Should I remove it `$1`? like this > `print  FS arr1[$1]" :[ NotMatch ] : "$0`

Comment: @hyun.ji, your welcome  yes you are right. I have removed that $1 FS part from code now, kindly check and confirm me. I could go for tonight's sleep then once you confirm soon cheers

Comment: I removed `$1 FS` and it printed correctly...  
`/         80G    xfs  /dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root   :[ NotMatch  ] : /         33G    xfs  /dev/mapper/rhel-root`  I'm very happy~~  Have a good night's sleep !!!  thanks you!!!

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this question, but could you please aline the fields `": [Blabla] :"` ?
Like the result of my question,,
even if I try, it doesn't work well.

Comment: @hyun.ji, you mean to say match, no-match all those keywords alignment in output? Kindly confirm once, by the way it could be tricky since string lengths output is not even.

Comment: I would like to aline baseline the above `[Notmatch], [ ok ], [NotExist]..`  .. I found it.  I think it'd be good to use the column command! `# sh volumes.sh | column -t -s ":"`.. Very nice!

Comment: @hyun.ji, sure, good to know, thanks for sharing, cheers.